# Unable to load controller-specific javascript file in Rails (5+)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, assets, pipeline

I have tried as many potential solutions as I can find and, so far, nothing has worked. The code in the .js file is not being executed nor does it appear to be present anywhere in the client browser.

application.html.erb loads this partial in the head:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
```

config/initializers/assets.rb

```
%w(  articles password_resets sessions static_pages users ).each do |controller|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js.coffee", "#{controller}.css"]
end
```

[controller-name-here].js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('My controller');
});
```

In the browser, when everything above is as it is, there will be an asset called ‘[controller-name].self.longstringhere.js?body=1’. It will have this code in it:

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

… which does not exist anywhere in my project. If I remove the controller from the assets.rb, when trying to load a page from that controller, it throws an error [as expected]. When getting rid of the entry in the application layout, the ‘[controller].self.js’ file is missing from the browser’s assets [as expected]. However, whether or not any of the controllers’ js files are missing or not doesn’t cause any errors and does not preclude the browser’s assets from including the ‘[controller].self.js’. It is like the files in app/assets/javascripts are totally ignored and “stubbed out”.

**NOTE:** I specifically do not have '//= require_tree .' and '*= require_tree .' in the application.js/.css files as I am specifically following the instructions [here](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/). This is intentional.

I have also removed all references that I can find (gem’s, assets, etc.) of turbolinks as I have been reading that this can cause evil things to happen that may relate to this issue.

I have also restarted the server, precompiled the assets, and have done this and several other ritualistic things many times - all to no avail.

For the record, I also changed the "#{controller}.js.coffee" in the assets.rb to just ‘.js’ to no avail. But I read that this isn’t necessary anyway.

This problem is with all controller’s – not just one in particular.

Thanks for your help!

**[EDIT]** I created a new rails project using scaffolding and followed the same procedure (but ensuring that the precompiled asset (posts.js) was called out specifically by name in assets.rb) and have the same problem as described above including the same javascript "stub" code in the browser's posts.blahblah.js file.

Comment: It should work, but make sure controller name and js/css file name should be same, Like if your controller name is `rooms_controller.rb` then js should be `rooms.coffee or room.js etc...`

Comment: I tried hard-coding the controller's assets name directly for good measure. (Always remembering to restart the service, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your file name is `[controller-name-here].js` and you are using js not coffee.

But you are adding coffee file in your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file. that's why it's not able to compile file properly.
Try change your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file like below:

```
%w(  articles password_resets sessions static_pages users ).each do |controller|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js", "#{controller}.css"]
end
```

Everything else seems fine.

Comment: This was one of my first thoughts and it didn't help. I tried again for good measure. I also hard-coded the controller's .js filename in. Either way, according to this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets, that precompilation is only necessary for css and coffeescript. This one has got me good. Again, the .js assets show up in the browser as "stubs" like I mentioned in my comment - not my code. I tried rake tmp:cache:clear as well.

Comment: The problem is coffee-script. I am not using it. I have removed all references to it (except the gem). Coffeescript resolves to the controller-name.js when it precompiles. This causes the files by the same name to be ignored. If I change the names and updated everything accordingly, it works fine. But, I cannot get rid of coffeescript. Once I delete the gem, everything fails (rails assets:precompile -> 'LoadError: cannot load such file -- coffee_script'; going to any of the pages -> 'cannot load such file -- coffee_script', and so on. I have cleared the cache, and whatever else I can find..

Comment: If you have ANY files with an extension of .coffee it will cause this error.